# Javascript ES6+, using bracket notation to access module global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to access a global variable inside an es6 module using the bracket notation, basically doing something like this:

```
const GLOBAL = 'something'

console.log(this['GLOBAL']) // evaluates to undefined, of course
```

Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: are you trying to access this identifier from different module or the same one? what do you mean under 'global' in this case?

Comment: Global from where? If it's inside the same module but declared at the top then just `console.log(GLOBAL)` will work - if it's in another module then `export\import` will work - it's a bit unclear what you mean by `global`

Comment: Module variables are not global, that's why you cannot access them as properties at all.

Comment: In the same module, within some function which receives a parameter, by which i would like to create a reference to the variable with bracket notation

Comment: I guess i could wrap them in an object... that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Global constants do not become part of the widnow object, unlike var.
This declaration creates a constant whose scope can be either global or local to the block in which it is declared, but if left alone in the global, they do not become property of the window object.